# Dynamic/scrollable container size in Cytoscape (+ cy.fit() issues)

Tags: cytoscape.js

So I've been giving Cytoscape a try recently. My project's goal is basically a collaborative graph that people will be able to add/remove nodes to/from, making it grow in the process. The graph will include many compound nodes.

Most of the examples I've seen use container div that takes 100% of the screen space. This is fine for "controlled" graphs but won't work in my case because its size is intended to be dynamic.

Here's a JSFiddle using the `circle` layout within a fixed 3000px/3000px container:
https://jsfiddle.net/Jeto143/zj8ed82a/5/

1. Is there any way to have the container size be dynamic as opposed to stating it explicitly? Or do I have to compute the new optimal container size each time somehow, and then call `cy.resize()`?
   **edit**: actually, using 100%/100% into `cy.fit()` might just work no matter how large the network is gonna be, so please ignore this question is this is the case.
2. Is there a recommended layout for displaying large/unknown amounts of data in a non-hierarchical way that would "smartly" place nodes (including compound ones) in the most efficient way possible, all the while avoiding any overlap? (I guess that's a lot to ask...)
3. Why doesn't `cy.fit()` seem to be working in my example? I'm using it both at graph initialization and when CTRL+clicking nodes (to show closed neighborhood), but it doesn't seem to like the 3000x3000px container (seems better with 100%x100%).
   **edit**: also ignore this question if you ignored 1., as again it seems fine with 100%/100%.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: It's (1).

Cytoscape has a pannable viewport, like a map.  You can define the dimensions of the viewport (div) in CSS.  What's displayed in the viewport is a function of the positions of the nodes, the zoom level, and the pan level -- just like what is visible in a map's viewport is a function of zoom, pan, and positions of points of interest.

So either you have to

(a) rethink your UI in terms of zoom and pan and use those in-built facilities in Cytoscape, or

(b) disable zoom and pan in Cytoscape (probably stay at (0, 0) at zoom 1) and let the user scroll the page as you add content to the graph and resize its container div to accommodate the new content.